# Inno Setup : Create Uninstall Registry Key only when needed

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation, registrykey

I need to force the directive `CreateUninstallRegKey` in the `[Setup]` Section to only create the Registry Key for uninstall when needed.

*For example , if I set a condition to create Uninstall Registry Key,
it must only be created when the condition goes True.
Otherwise the Uninstall Registry Key must not be created.*

How can I do this in Inno Setup?

***UPDATED QUESTION***

The code I wrote is:

```
[Setup]
CreateUninstallRegKey=RegKeyDeterminer

[Code]
function RegKeyDeterminer(): Boolean;
  begin
  Result:= ISDoneError = True;
  if ISDoneError = True then Result:= True;
end;
```

**With this code , The Uninstall Registry Key is always creating. (It should be something wrong in the code I wrote.)**

*The Uninstall Registry Key must not be created if ISDoneError = True.*

*The Uninstall Registry Key must be created if ISDoneError = False.*

*`ISDoneError` only has True or False values.(It is a Boolean Function in `ISDone.dll` which is a Dynamic Link Library that used to extract files from 7-Zip,RAR,Binary etc. archives in Inno Setup.)*

These are the conditions.
If you can see any mistakes or condition setting errors , then correct my code.

Thank You.

Comment: *"If I set a condition"* - What condition? Can you give us an example when you need to create the key, and when not?

Comment: Okay without giving you my condition, I made my work worst. See my UPDATED QUESTION.

Comment: Your solution to error handling does not look right. You should not allow the installer to even finish, when something goes wrong. Not hack it by **pretending** that the installer did not finish.

Comment: So should I remove the line `if ISDoneError = True then Result:= True` from it to resolve this wrong behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`CreateUninstallRegKey` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_createuninstallregkey) can take a [boolean expression/function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptexpression) as its value.

So just implement the function to return `True` when you need to create the key and `False` otherwise.

```
 [Setup]
 CreateUninstallRegKey=CreateKey

 [Code]

 function CreateKey: Boolean;
 begin
   Result := condition;
 end;
```